# Passing the JavaScript variable into HTML

Tags: javascript, asp.net

My JavaScript code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     var current = 0;
var cars = new Array(5);
cars[0] = "Audi";
cars[1] = "Bentley";
cars[2] = "Mercedes";
cars[3] = "Mini";
cars[4] = "BMW";
document.getElementById("addCarBtn").onclick = function () {
    if (!(current > cars.length - 1)) {
        document.getElementById("carsDiv").innerHTML += cars[current] + "<br />";
        current++;
    }
}
</script>
```

I want to display the value of each array item one by one on button click the div.

But when i click the button, the array[0] i.e "Audi" is displayed but just for fraction of seconds. then it disappears and only the button is visible.

Comment: post your html-code of the content which should hold the array values

Comment: <div id="JValue"></div>. The value will be displayed inside the div.

Comment: And what is the HTML for the button? Did you try anything yourself?

Comment: i tried the code below: <div id="carsDiv">
</div>
<button id="addCarBtn">Add Car</button>
<script>
var current = 0;
var cars = new Array(5);
cars[0] = "Audi";
cars[1] = "Bentley";
cars[2] = "Mercedes";
cars[3] = "Mini";
cars[4] = "BMW";
document.getElementById("addCarBtn").onclick = function() {
       if (!(current > cars.length - 1))
       {
            document.getElementById("carsDiv").innerHTML += cars[current] + "<br />";
            current++;
       }
}
</script> but its showing the error: Unable to set property 'onclick' of undefined or null reference

Comment: Please edit your question with what you posted above in the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a loop like:-

```
for(var i=0; i< cars.length;i++)
{
alert(cars[i]);
}
```

//It will show alert 5 times. You'll need to click through ok to traverse all array elements.
//I think it is what you're thinking, or have I interpreted it wrong.

// I'm assuming you're completely new to javascript then on your button write onclick="yourFuncName();"

```
function YourfuncName()
{
//Initailze your array here, like you have done or like kamituel has done
// then just print each array element one by one 
for(var i=0; i< cars.length;i++)
{
alert(cars[i]);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about the `every` method?

```
cars.every( function(c) {
    alert("car: " + c);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there. Since the JS code was located before the HTML, the button element still doesn't exist. Best just wrap the code with `window.onload` and it should work:

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("addCarBtn").onclick = function() {
        if (!(current > cars.length - 1)) {
            document.getElementById("carsDiv").innerHTML += cars[current] + "<br />";
            current++;
        }
    }
};
```

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/zwAK5/1/).

Edit: just noticed your button doesn't have type. This means that some browsers might make it a submit button by default, which will cause a page reload. To avoid it, make it a plain button:

```
<button id="addCarBtn" type="button">
```